# Selecting the last 7 days from Now() in MYSQL(if no data return 0)

Tags: mysql, django-rest-framework

How to select the last 7 days from Now() in MYSQL, if no data return 0? I pasted SQL as below, is there anybody who knows how to solve it?

Thanks so much for any advice.

````
```SQL
SELECT SUM(pv) AS pv_count,  
DATE_FORMAT(insert_time,'%Y-%m-%d') AS visit_date
FROM visit 
-- WHERE insert_time >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(insert_time,'%Y-%m-%d')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(insert_time,'%Y-%m-%d') DESC
LIMIT 7
```

  pv_count   visit_date
    19091   2022-02-28
    22342   2022-02-25
    42342   2022-02-24
    92532   2022-02-23
    62353   2022-02-22
    67234   2022-02-21
    22342   2022-02-19
````

I got output as above SQL, but that's not the data what I need, my expected output is as below(I added some data in this link [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec22e1db5c0085aadf8059cfb1969a06)):

```
  pv_count   visit_date
    0       2022-03-06
    0       2022-03-05
    0       2022-03-04
    0       2022-03-03
    0       2022-03-02
    0       2022-03-01
    19091   2022-02-28
```

or as below:

```
visit_date  2022-02-28 2022-03-01 2022-03-02 2022-03-03 2022-03-04 2022-03-05 2022-03-06
pv_count     19091        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
```

Why did I paste two expected outputs? Because I really need a easy way to solve it, I have more than 10 tables to return these data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a calendar table here, which is a table containing all the dates you want to appear in your report.  Consider the following query:

```sql
SELECT d.dt, SUM(v.pv) AS pv_count
FROM
(
    SELECT '2022-02-28' AS dt UNION ALL SELECT '2022-03-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2022-03-02' UNION ALL SELECT '2022-03-03' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2022-03-04' UNION ALL SELECT '2022-03-05' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2022-03-06'
) d
LEFT JOIN visit v
    ON d.dt = DATE(v.insert_time) AND
       v.insert_time >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY
    d.dt
ORDER BY
    dt.DESC
LIMIT 7;
```

Note that in practice the inline subquery aliased as `d` above can be replaced with a bona fide table containing all the dates you need.

Comment: Hi, Is there any easy way to solve it? Cause you wrote `'2022-02-28'`, `2022-03-02`, the data will change every day

Comment: Please read my entire answer, which mentions twice that you need an actual table containing all the dates you want to appear in the report.

Comment: Hi, I add some data in this link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec22e1db5c0085aadf8059cfb1969a06